# SMB shares on migrated VM no longer accessible from windows 7

Tags: server-message-block

I have a Centos VM that has a Samba server with a couple of network volumes that are normally accessed from my Win 7 workstation. I temporarily moved the VM from its normal ESXi host to another Vmware server platform so that the ESXi host could be upgraded. The VM worked fine in its temporary location but now that it's been returned to the upgraded ESXi platform windows can no longer access the shares, giving the following error message when trying to open them:

> \CENTOSBD7NU4\admin is not
>   accessible. You might not have
>   permission to use this network
>   resource. Contact the administrator of
>   this server to find out if you have
>   access permissions.
>
> The specified network name is no
>   longer available

The VM is visible in windows explorer and the shares are listed. Does anyone know what I should do next to restore the connection to the shares? Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Im not sure if this will be helpful in Ur case but it helped me a lot wit Win 7 as well:

http://wiki.samba.org/index.php/Windows7

I know that Vista and Win7 have some problems with SAMBA, but Im not sure how it looks in VMware case.

Comment: Thanks for the link. Actually I discovered what the problem was - the VMs virtual disk was full. quite understandably lots of things stopped working, including Samba. I deleted some stuff and it all works again.